# Overflow hidden not hiding background from parent

Tags: css, overflow

The example i provided is a simplified version of the issue i'm currently experiencing, I'm trying to get rid of the small 1px red border that appears when I set border radius and overflow:hidden. Ideally you would see no red at all around the image. I have tried different css properties like isolation, border-collapse, masking but nothing seems to work perfectly. It seems like when i add and explicit height and width to my container then i get the desired effect but in the my actual situation the width and height are fluid.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 100px;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/eagle-png/bald-eagle-png-transparent-image-pngpix-7.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried border: hidden

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't seem to do anything. I'm thinking has something to do with like anti-aliasing or something.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `img` `{display: block}`. Because images are by default `inline` they have some default browser margin.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 100px;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/eagle-png/bald-eagle-png-transparent-image-pngpix-7.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```